# Override/disable 3rd party plugin (Amasty Shop By) which is not declared

Tags: magento2, plugin, third-party-plugin, amasty

I've been battling with this one for a while but can't figure out how to disable, in order to override, a plugin in the Amasty Shop by extension. I need to override a couple of methods in the plugin, but as they're set to private and use private variables declared within the class, I think I have to just disable that specific plugin and override it with my own.

The issue I have is that the plugin doesn't appear to be declared/named in the di.xml files present in the extension, but there are some additional plugins in the extension which extend it, and these plugins are named in di.xml.

The plugin I am trying to override is here: `vendor/amasty/shopby/Plugin/Ajax/Ajax.php`

There are 2 plugins (in the same directory as the above) which extend it, and are named in `vendor/amasty/shopby/etc/frontend/di.xml` as below:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Shopby::ajaxInject" type="Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\CategoryViewAjax"/>
    </type>
```

I've created and registered my module, and my attempt to disable and override the plugin is as follows:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\Ajax">
        <plugin name="Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\Ajax" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="my_ajax" type="MyNamespace\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\Ajax" />
    </type>
</config>
```

It's likely I'm missing something obvious here, grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your `di.xml` code is wrong.

### Why

`Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\CategoryViewAjax` is plugin type and it is plugin of `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View`. `Amasty_Shopby::ajaxInject` is plugin name.

A plugin Type is disabled by Plugin name means `Amasty_Shopby::ajaxInject` not plugin Type `Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\CategoryViewAjax`.

Also, `<type name="Amasty\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\Ajax">` is  wrong it should be `<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">`

So, your `di.xml` will be

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">
>         <plugin name="Amasty_Shopby::ajaxInject" disabled="true" />
>         <plugin name="my_ajax" type="MyNamespace\Shopby\Plugin\Ajax\Ajax" />
>     </type>
> </config>
> ```

Also, make your **MyNamespace_Shopby** should depend on `Amasty_Shopby`.

So, you have to modify your `module.xml`  like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyNamespace_Shopby"  setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Amasty_Shopby"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```